# Hybris with Angular frontend

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

In hybris projects that use angular in the frontend, we are create angular components and add a proxy like this one to do the mapping and call the service:

```
{
"/hybris/*": {
   "target": "<sap-nw-gateway-host>:<sap-nw-gateway-port>",
   "secure": false,
   "logLevel" : “info”
}
}
```

My question is:
How do we manage these components on the hybris side? On the cms cockpit, for instance.

Thanks in advance,
Jookje

Comment: Do you know the 'Spartacus' Framework from Hybris? https://github.com/SAP/spartacus. It is their solution, how to build an angular FrontEnd to Hybris Commerce Cloud. Maybe you can use this as well or have a look for some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the 'Spartacus' Framework in our project to communicate with Hybris BE. (I add this as a comment). Without going to deep in detail, it is about creating `FlexComponents` in Hybris CMS BE. Here is an example:

```
INSERT_UPDATE CMSFlexComponent; $contentCV[unique = true]; uid[unique = true]; name                ; flexType            ; &componentRef
                          ;                          ; SiteLogoComponent ; Site LogoComponent ; xxxLogoComponent ; SiteLogoComponent
```